# Deleting database records MVC

Tags: php, mysql, model-view-controller

I've built a MVC 'framework' for learning purposes, and I'm struggling with this problem:

I am working on a CRUD application and I don't know how I should delete the records from my database. Right now I'am doing it through URL.

`example.com/controller/delete/id` that is how I delete a record from the database. I don't really like this way, because anyone could unintentionally or intentionally delete database records.

So my question is: How should I implement this feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a number of issues here:

First of all, you need to know who is performing the operation, then you need to decide if they're allowed to do it.

For the first, you need a login system which issues a session id to the client (usually via cookie). You then use the session id on the server to look up who the user is and check if they're allowed to do the delete. This is usually handled through granting roles to users and then allowing roles to perform certain actions

Incidentally, `GET` requests are used for requests that do not modify the server state and can be repeated with no side-effects. `POST`, (or `PUT`/`DELETE`) should be used for any action that makes changes. Browsers will not send a POST twice without prompting the user explicitly.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I already got a login, but still users could mess up. Thank you for your answer, I don't know how I couldn't think about using POST before.

Comment: Re: Users messing up, yeah POST makes it hard to do by mistake, and of course if you're serving a UI, you can put the usual confirmation mechanisms in place. If you _really_ want to prevent any mistakes, make deletes a 2-step process. First you request a delete and get a token, then repeat the request with the token. Insanely over-engineered but impossible to do by mistake

Answer (score 1):

You need to include a security layer to your MVC in order to define who can access specific resources of your API.

The most simple way is to require a key parameter in the URL that needs to match a key that you would have predefined on the server side, but be aware that despite it will prevent random user to update your data, it might not be suitable depending on the security level you want to achieve for your application.

Comment: Include your auth token in the url so it can be recorded in every log between you and the server?

Comment: Yes. As I said, this is the most simple way. Not the most secured way.
Your code also will need to access the key in a clear fashion which is not secured.

There are many way to implement a security layer and it is a vast topic. I would recommend you make some research on the topic to find the most suitable solution for your application.

Comment: Hi @basic , maybe I should have emphasis more the fact that "the most simple way" it is not the most secure way, but I believe your negative comment was just because of a misunderstanding between you and I, what do you think ?

Comment: Sorry, I was away from the computer. The main reason for the downvote is that you recommended a method that would leave the OP vulnerable with no warning. If you were to say `The easiest is X but it's insecure because of Y` or (even better) `The easiest is X but it's insecure so use Z instead`. If you'd care to edit your answer, I'd be happy to change my vote.

Comment: I modified my answer hope its more clear now. Thanks for for feedback.

Answer (score 1):

You need to send data with `POST` data.

you can also use `GET` with [`CSRF`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-site_request_forgery) token

I think both way is good.

Comment: POST won't prevent anybody from requesting your API. CSRF token is not related to GET or POST but is use to guaranty that the form is sent from your website.

Comment: @maalls I answer it for this part of question. "unintentionally", CSRF can use for GET when you want user can only sent one request.